# Update Field based upon matching 2 fields in another table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update

This is my first post so be gentle ;)

I'm trying to update a field on `Table1` column based upon matching data on 2 columns in `Table 1` & `Table 2`.

Column Names are :

```
Table1.KeyField = Table2.KeyField
Table1.FieldName = Table2.FieldName
```

Column to update in `Table 1` is `NumericValue` with a zero.

Every way I have tried results in error :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your update query? How should we help you to correct your sql query without seeing it?

Comment: Run the subquery independently.  Look at what it's returning.  Decide what row you want and determine a way to get it.

Answer (score 1):

```
update t
set    t.NumericValue = ???
from   Table1 t
join   Table2 t2
on     t.KeyField = t2.KeyField
and    t.FieldName = t2.FieldName
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample data:

```
create table Table1 (KeyField int,FieldName varchar(20),Targetcolumntoupdate numeric(5,2));
create table Table2 (KeyField int,FieldName varchar(20),Sourcecolumntoupdate numeric(5,2));
insert into Table1 values  (1,'F1',0.00);
insert into Table1 values  (2,'F1',0.00);
insert into Table2 values  (1,'F1',1.00);
insert into Table2 values  (1,'F1',2.00);
```

Are you tring to update a column in Table1 as :

```
-- Wrong approach possible cause of error stated
Update Table1
Set Table1.Targetcolumntoupdate = 
( SELECT (T2.Sourcecolumntoupdate)
FROM Table1 T1 
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON
T1.KeyField = T2.KeyField AND T1.FieldName = T2.FieldName) ;
```

then it's wrong as you can see the sub query you have created to select the required data for updating Targetcolumntoupdate will return multiple possible values.

**Correct Query is as follows:**

```
Update T1
Set T1.Targetcolumntoupdate = (T2.Sourcecolumntoupdate)
FROM Table1 T1 
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON
T1.KeyField = T2.KeyField AND T1.FieldName = T2.FieldName;
```

Hope this helps!!!